# How can I call SharePoint to convert a DOCX/PPTX/XLSX to PDF (and HTML)?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

SharePoint has the functionality to convert an OpenXml file to PDF. (And maybe HTML?)

Is there a way to programmatically call SharePoint to make this conversion? And if so, how?

Preferably a way that can work with SharePoint Online

Answer (score 0):

We have used a third party - Muhimbi Converter Service Online(REST API\ Power Automate) to Convert files to PDF.

You can find more details at https://support.muhimbi.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002816048-Getting-started-with-the-PDF-Converter-Services-Online

You can find the code sample its https://github.com/Muhimbi/PDF-Converter-Services-Online

They also provide an option to Free subscription and Free Trial so you can evaluate the product.

Comment: There are a ton of convertors out there, including one we wrote. But none are a perfect match and we need to use SharePoint when a perfect match is required. Also, I assume you work for Muhimbi in which case you should say so in your answer.